# Убрать лишнее подзапросом

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите пожалуйста понять, как сделать выборку в задаче:
Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно найти животных, которые не едят аллергичную еду
Если я делаю вот такую выборку, то вываливаются все строки, исключая аллергичные продукты, но мне нужно исключить животных, которые могут их есть (т.е. в итоге должен остаться только лось)

```
SELECT д.animal
FROM диета д
join цвет ц on д.meal = ц.meal
join аллергия а on a.color = ц.color
where а.allergy not in ('да')
```

И я совсем не понимаю, как составить запрос (подзапрос), чтобы исключить самих животных.

Comment: `HAVING SUM(allergy = 'угу') = 0`

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, попробовала, но получила в ответ: FUNCTION table.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: `SELECT д.animal 
FROM диета д
join цвет ц on д.meal = ц.meal
join аллергия а on a.color = ц.color group by д.animal
having sum(а.allergy = 'да') = 0`. Если не выполнится - уберите кириллицу. Если не поможет - выбрасывайте программу-клиент.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример

```
select * from exampl_diet d1 
where d1.animal not in(
    -- Получаем список всех животных которые могут есть аллергенные продукты
    select distinct d.animal from exampl_diet d
    where d.meal in (
        -- Получаем список всех аллергенных продуктов
        select meal from exampl_color c, exampl_allergy a 
        where c.color=a.color and a.allergy = 'да' 
    )
)
```

структуры таблиц для примера

```
CREATE TABLE `exampl_allergy` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `color` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `allergy` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `exampl_color` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `meal` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `exampl_diet` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `animal` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meal` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я сначала внешние ключи настроил

```
SELECT animal_meal.animal
FROM animal_meal
INNER JOIN color_meal ON color_meal.meal = animal_meal.meal
INNER JOIN allergy_color ON allergy_color.color = color_meal.color
GROUP BY animal_meal.animal
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT allergy_color.allergy) = 'нет'
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант, он должен работать:

```
SELECT DISTINCT д.animal
FROM диета д
LEFT JOIN цвет ц on д.meal = ц.meal
LEFT JOIN аллергия а on a.color = ц.color
WHERE а.allergy = 'нет'
```

Хотя если Вы дополнительно избавитесь от кириллицы в именах таблиц, это будет очень правильное решение.